# import android.hardware.Camera does have open() method

Tags: android, android-camera

```
Android Studio 0.4.6
```

Hello,

I am trying to use the camera and I have set the permissions like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

I have imported the correct package:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

And I try and open the camera like this:

```
Camera camera = Camera. there is no open method;
```

All I get are the following:

```
Parameters
Class
Size
```

I have follow the developer documentation, I can't see I have done anything wrong.

many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to paste `camera = Camera.open();` or type it in manually. Sometimes the "clever" thing glitches.

By the way, did the tool suggest to `import android.hardware.Camera;` or you typed it manually? I mean, is it an Android project? (Typically you start with the automatically generated hello world example and then add extra functionality to it, if you did something else, it's easier to re-do it from the very beginning.)

Comment: That did work as I was able to run the project. However, I am convinced its a bug with Android Studio. I have just opened the same project on my MacBook Air and I get all the methods from that class.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future facing the same issue

```
import android.hardware.*;
```